# Bot v4 web chat channel, sending the message very slowly

Tags: botframework

I am using the latest v4 web chat react lib. In the emulator things works fine and quick. But when i deploy it on azure and use the webchat channel, and type a message and send, the "Sending" label appears and stay a little and then says "Just now". The problem is that its very slow and the sending label actually stay for like 2 seconds. What could be the possible cause here ?

[image: a busy cat]

The same issue has been raised in github https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1172

Answer (score 1):

It's indicative of how fast your user message is hitting the bot endpoint. The emulator is local, and thus, a bit faster (2 seconds in this case).

"Sending" means the user has sent off the message, and the "Just now" message means the bot has read the user's message. It's apparently taking 2 seconds for your bot to hit your azure endpoint. In order to turn from "sending" to "sent", the Direct Line channel need to explicitly tell Web Chat that the bot has read it. Technically, it means Direct Line channel will send the copy of the user's message back to Web Chat again.

For example, for this story.

1. User say "My name is John"
2. Bot say "Hello, John"

   - If you look at the network traffic from Direct Line channel in the browser, you should see a few packets send or receive in this particular order:

     1. HTTP POST "My name is John", returns 200 OK
     2. HTTP GET 200 OK for "Hello, John" (or as Web Socket packet)
     3. HTTP GET 200 OK for "My name is John" (or as Web Socket packet)
   - If the 3rd packet is not received, Web Chat will not consider the message is successfully sent.
   - If you are using our Direct Line channel (not custom bot adapter), Direct Line channel will make up the 3rd packet for you automatically, as long as the bot respond "positively and timely" for the HTTP request "My name is John" from Direct Line channel. In other words, if the bot is error-ed out or taking too long time while processing the user's message, Web Chat will not change to "Just Now" status because it's a negative response. (For timeout, I believe the hard deadline is 120s.)

If you have Application Insights added to your bot, you can look at the dashboard to review the network traffic:

[image: application insights example dashboard]